# Google Recaptcha v2 get requests fail

Tags: recaptcha

I incorporated a v2 invisible Google recaptcha in a comment form, it always worked correctly. From yesterday it stops working and I got these messages in console during the recaptcha rendering (Chrome version 71.0.3578.98)

GET https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2//styles__ltr.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
GET https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2//recaptcha__it.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
Uncaught ReferenceError: recaptcha is not defined
    at anchor:179

the problem seems to be the missing part in both url after api2/

On the same browser, in incognito mode, everything works properly and the fetched urls are:
https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1545073489967/styles__ltr.css
https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1545073489967/recaptcha__it.js

The same problem occurs using FF both in standard and incognito mode while in Edge it works.
Cleaning the cache, deleting the cookies and rebooting PC (WIn10) don't resolve the problem. On a macOS machine the problem does not occur either in chrome or in ff, any idea ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would check those URLs are correct, they show others in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible

Comment: The problem was due to the Ghostery addon which blocked the "dobleclick" tracker probably required by Google Recaptcha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the problem is caused by ad blockers like Ghostery and Adblock Plus. Allowing tracking on the site solved this problem for me.